# Http call from a service inside a directive controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I am building an Angular directive to load a Highchart.js area graph passing some variables from it.

I am using the directive like this

```
<andamento-fondo-area-chart color="#3FAE2A" url="../data.json"></andamento-fondo-area-chart>
```

I am trying to pass the url with the json data from the directive itself, make the http call through a service and then use the data inside the directive itself to build the graph.

Below you can see the code I wrote for the service and the directive.
In the directive controller, after the service call I send the $scope to the console and then I send the $scope.data.

What I am not understanding is when I output the $scope, I have the data array inside it, filled with my data. On the next line output the $scope.data itself and it gives me "undefined".

[image: see image to see my console output]

Do you have any idea why?

```
 //Service
    OLS.service('dataService', function($http) {
        delete $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
        this.getData = function(url) {
            return $http({
                url: url
            });
        }
    });

//Graph Directive using Highchart

OLS.directive('andamentoFondoAreaChart', function($http, dataService){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div id="areaGraphContainer" style="width:100%;"></div>',
        scope: {
            url: '@',
            color: '@'
        },
        controller: function($scope){       
            dataService.getData($scope.url).then(function(dataResponse) {
                $scope.data = dataResponse;
            }); 
            console.log($scope);
            console.log($scope.data);           
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {        
            Highcharts.chart('areaGraphContainer', {
                chart: {
                    type: 'area',
                    ...
                },
                title.: {
                    ...
                },
                ...,
                series: [{
                    color: scope.color,
                    ...,
                    data: scope.data
                }]
            });
        }
    };  
});
```

Comment: `dataService.getData($scope.url).then(function(dataResponse) {
                $scope.data = dataResponse;
                console.log($scope);
                console.log($scope.data);
            }); 
            `
What if you do like this?

Comment: @Chrillewoodz if i call it inside the service it returns the data correctly. But i need them outside the service, in particular i need it inside the link function of the directive. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look here:

```
dataService.getData($scope.url).then(function(dataResponse) {
            $scope.data = dataResponse;
        }); 
console.log($scope);
console.log($scope.data);
```

When you try to print $scope.data, $scope doesn't have it, because dataService don't completed request, try to acces $scope.data inside .then:

```
dataService.getData($scope.url).then(function(dataResponse) {
            $scope.data = dataResponse;
            console.log($scope.data); 
        });
```

**UPDATE**

Maybe try this with $watch?

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {  
      scope.$watch('data', function(newVal) {
        if(newVal) { Highcharts.chart('areaGraphContainer', ...);}
    }, true);
```

Comment: If i call it inside the "then" event i have the data, the problem is i have to bind those data into the scope so that I can use them into the "link" function of the directive to embed the data into the graph, as you can see in the series.data property of the chart call i set it equal to scope.data, but of course the data don't get there. Plus: the strange thing is that when i print just the scope i have the data in the object data, but when i print the scope.data i haven't it. Btw thanks for the help.

Comment: The updated answer works. Thank you so much. So basically the "watch" function just "wait" for the data to be filled? I am sorry I ask but I am relatively new to angular and I'm just trying to learn as fast as i can.

Comment: Yep, in this case "watch" just "wait" the data. BUT, if $scope.data changes, $watch will be called again.

Comment: Thank you so much. If it's not too much bother I have one last big picture question so that i can learn: you can see the code I wrote, the question is: is this that the right way to do what I need? Or is there something I can do better? Thank you very much

Comment: I don't a big PRO in Angular and the only thing that I can say - if i did simillar task, i did it the same way.

Comment: If waiting for async data then using a watcher is the correct way to do so yes.